# Optaplanner custom phase command fails in native build, can't find generated Gizmo supplier

Tags: quarkus, optaplanner

Using Optaplanner 8.6.0.Final, Quarkus 1.13.4.Final

I have built a custom phase using the CustomPhaseCommand interface:

```
@RegisterForReflection
public class InitPhase implements CustomPhaseCommand<Schedule> {
   ...
}
```

It is configured like this in solverConfig.xml:

```
<customPhase>
    <customPhaseCommandClass>org.acme.InitPhase</customPhaseCommandClass>
</customPhase>
```

But when running **the native build it fails** at startup:

```
ERROR [io.qua.run.Application] (main) Failed to start application (with profile prod): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Impossible state: could not find the CustomPhaseConfig's customPhaseCommandClass (org.acme.InitPhase) generated Gizmo supplier.
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.util.ConfigUtils.newInstance(ConfigUtils.java:34)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:119)
    at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(GeneratedMain.zig:29)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.phase.custom.DefaultCustomPhaseFactory.createCustomPhaseCommand(DefaultCustomPhaseFactory.java:69)

    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.phase.custom.DefaultCustomPhaseFactory.buildPhase(DefaultCustomPhaseFactory.java:53)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.phase.custom.DefaultCustomPhaseFactory.buildPhase(DefaultCustomPhaseFactory.java:31)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverFactory.buildPhaseList(DefaultSolverFactory.java:177)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverFactory.buildSolver(DefaultSolverFactory.java:99)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverManager.validateSolverFactory(DefaultSolverManager.java:68)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverManager.<init>(DefaultSolverManager.java:57)
    at org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.SolverManager.create(SolverManager.java:111)
```

Can I generate the Gizmo supplier manually somehow? It all works just fine when not running it native.

Comment: This is a bug apparently, `<customPhaseCommandClass>` is currently not compatible with a native build. Thank you for reporting it, Chris is looking into it.

Comment: Thanks. Will it work by using domain access type REFLECTION for the time being?

Comment: Created a PR to fix the issue here: https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/pull/1334 ; using domain access type REFLECTION will not fix the issue.